# Why can't I concat strings for class variable definition in PHP?

Tags: php

Inside my classes, Why I am able to declare a variable and set its value at the same time like this

```
 public $CSS_reset = "someValue";
```

Yet a syntax error occurs when i try to append two variables or strings like this

```
 public $CSS_reset = "someValue" . "appendedValue";
```

The syntax error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

This is my code ...
with no syntax errors

```
class MyClass {

    private $css = "Mysite/CSS/";
    private $js = "Mysite/JS/"; 

    public $CSS_reset;        //Declare $CSS_reset but set it's value in the constructor
    public $CSS_styles; 


    function __construct() 
    {
         $CSS_reset = "reset.css" . "reset2.css";
         $CSS_styles = "styles.css" . "styles2.css";

    }

}
```

This is my code with syntax errors...

```
class MyClass {

    private $css = "Mysite/CSS/";
    private $js = "Mysite/JS/"; 

    public $CSS_reset = "reset.css" . "reset2.css";
    public $CSS_styles = "styles.css" . "styles2.css";

}
```

Not that I don't want to use the Constructor but the 2nd option with a syntax error is less code.

Comment: `$this` refers to the _instance_ of the class, and at that point there is no instance of it yet.

Comment: _This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated_ http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: You don't have a constructer

Comment: Please post error message to this posting to give it more value.

Comment: Unless you are trying to create static properties, why don't you want to use the constructor?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use the constructor but I would like to use less code. please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to uses the properties `css` as if they were static, but they are not.

```
function __construct() 
{
     $this->CSS_reset = $this->css . "reset.css";
     $this->CSS_styles = $this->css . "styles.css";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, your class object exists already - but in your code with syntax error it doesn't exist. That's why you can't use `$this->css` or even `var $xxx = "foo"."bar"`. So you've to use a constructor or write it like:

```
class MyClass {

    private $css = "Mysite/CSS/";
    private $js = "Mysite/JS/"; 

    public $CSS_reset = "Mysite/CSS/reset.css";
    public $CSS_styles = "Mysite/CSS/styles.css"; 

}
```

Comment: That's still a syntax error. The property declaration cannot be an expression. It must be a constant value.

Comment: Okay, than I change it like this - always a problem when you mix up too much js and php ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make statements like that outside a class method/constructor.

This use of `$this` in the property definition does not exist before the `__construct` is called.

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyClass {

    private $css = "Mysite/CSS/";
    private $js = "Mysite/JS/";

    public $CSS_reset;
    public $CSS_styles; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $CSS_reset =  $this->css . "reset.css";
        $CSS_styles = self::$css . "styles.css";
    }
}
```